# angular ng-tags-input; clicking outside the field

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Am using http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

The input field works and draws autocomplete data from a specified source. It's configured to present autocomplete matches after three characters have been typed in, and this works fine. What isn't quite fine is the behavior when I click outside the input field before having completed a selection. In that situation, a tag is formed with just the three (or however many) characters I typed.

One sees this same behavior on the example at the ngTagsInput link. (Example, type "gre" and then click outside of the input field. You get a tag labeled "gre".)

The way we'd like it to behave is that a click outside the field will leave the typed letters in place but will not convert them to a tag--exactly as it does if you press the Esc key.

Comment: Any luck with  `add-on-blur="false"` ?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thanks! I'd tried addOnBlur previously, though I hadn't believed it should be necessary, as we're using addOnAutocompleteOnly; and, according to the documentation, addOnBlur is among the flags ignored in that case.

However, while addOnBlur didn't have any effect, add-on-blur fixed the problem.